# Hadoop mapper is never called, custom input format might be the issue

Tags: java, hadoop

So I am doing a little test program just to get the hang of hadoops inputformat classes.  I had a word search already built which took in lines as values and searched for the word line by line.  I wanted to see if I could get hadoop to take in values word by word, hadoop doesn't seem to like that and keeps giving me results using the default mapper.  My mappers initialize function is never even called.

I do know my record reader is called and that it is doing more or less what it is supposed to and I'm pretty sure the output of the record reader is what my mapper is searching for so why does hadoop decide not to call it?

Here is the relevant code

Input Format Class

```
public class WordReader extends FileInputFormat<Text, Text> {

    @Override
    public RecordReader<Text, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit split,

    TaskAttemptContext context) {

        return new MyWholeFileReader();

    }   
}
```

Record Reader

```
public class MyWholeFileReader extends RecordReader<Text, Text> {

    private long start;

    private LineReader in;

    private Text key = null;

    private Text value = null;

    private ArrayList<String> outputvalues;

    public void initialize(InputSplit genericSplit,

    TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException {
        outputvalues = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileSplit split = (FileSplit) genericSplit;

        Configuration job = context.getConfiguration();

        start = split.getStart();

        final Path file = split.getPath();

        // open the file and seek to the start of the split

        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(job);

        FSDataInputStream fileIn = fs.open(split.getPath());

        in = new LineReader(fileIn, job);

        if (key == null) {

            key = new Text();

        }

        key.set(split.getPath().getName());

        if (value == null) {

            value = new Text();

        }

    }

    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException {

        if (outputvalues.size() == 0) {
            Text buffer = new Text();
            int i = in.readLine(buffer);
            String str = buffer.toString();
            for (String vals : str.split(" ")) {
                outputvalues.add(vals);
            }
            if (i == 0 || outputvalues.size() == 0) {
                key = null;
                value = null;
                return false;
            }
        }
        value.set(outputvalues.remove(0));
        System.out.println(value.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentKey() {
        return key;

    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentValue() {

        return value;

    }

    /**
     * 
     * Get the progress within the split
     */

    public float getProgress() {

        return 0.0f;

    }

    public synchronized void close() throws IOException {

        if (in != null) {

            in.close();

        }

    }

}
```

Mapper

```
public class WordSearchMapper extends  Mapper<Text, Text, OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable>, Reporter> {
    static String keyword;

    BloomFilter<String> b;
    public void configure(JobContext jobConf) {
        keyword = jobConf.getConfiguration().get("keyword");
        System.out.println("keyword>> " + keyword);
        b = new BloomFilter<String>(.01,10000);
        b.add(keyword);
        System.out.println(b.getExpectedBitsPerElement());
    }


    public void map(Text key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output,
            Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        int wordPos;
        System.out.println("value.toString()>> " + value.toString());
        System.out.println(((FileSplit) reporter.getInputSplit()).getPath()
                .getName());
        String[] tokens = value.toString().split("[\\p{P} \\t\\n\\r]");

        for (String st :tokens) {           
            if (b.contains(st)) {
                if (value.toString().contains(keyword)) {
                    System.out.println("Found one");
                    wordPos = ((Text) value).find(keyword);
                    output.collect(value, new IntWritable(wordPos));
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Driver:

```
public class WordSearch {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf,"WordSearch");


    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapperClass(WordSearchMapper.class);


    job.setInputFormatClass( WordReader.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    conf.set("keyword", "the");
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("search.txt"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("outputs"+System.currentTimeMillis()));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);  
    }
```

Comment: And I figured it out... this is why hadoop needs to stop supporting multiple versions of itself or why I should stop jamming multiple tutorials together.

Turns out my mapper needs to be set up like this for the way my mapper and record reader are set up to interact.

    public class WordSearchMapper extends  Mapper<Text, Text, Text,IntWritable> {
     static String keyword;
I only realized this after looking at my imports and seeing that reporter was from package org.apache.hadoop.mapred as opposed to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I figured it out... this is why hadoop needs to stop supporting multiple versions of itself or why I should stop jamming multiple tutorials together. Turns out my mapper needs to be set up like this for the way my mapper and record reader are set up to interact.

'public class WordSearchMapper extends Mapper { static String keyword;`

I only realized this after looking at my imports and seeing that reporter was from package org.apache.hadoop.mapred as opposed to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce –